# How can I trigger('click') on page load with this specific code

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this happen, on page load?

```
<a onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click');"><?php echo $text_write; ?></a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
    $('a[href="#tab-review"]').click();
});
```

[RTFM](http://api.jquery.com).

---

> Hm, any idea how to put this between  I need this to be executed with IF...?

```
<script>
function clickTheLink()
{
    $('a[href="#tab-review"]').click();
}

<?php
if ($something) {
  echo '$(window).load(clickTheLink);';
}
?>
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you recommend $window.load instead of what I consider to be the more "standard" $document.ready?

Comment: Because the OP used the words "on page load," not "on document ready."

Comment: Tnx for the answers, but can you please tell me how to implement that code? Just to replace mine, with that one, put it between <?php ?> or...? Sorry, can't figure it out :(

Comment: @Nikola place the JavaScript code in `<script>` tags, or in an external JS file referenced by a `<script>` tag. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script

Comment: Thank you guys for you awesome and quick help ;)

Comment: Hm, any idea how to put this between <?php ?> I need this to be executed with IF...?

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot. But is there any chance I can execute that within the code? For e.g the normal URL is .../product_id=41 and to add something and become like .../product_id=41#tab-review and with this second URL, the tab should be shown? Any changce of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming jquery.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('a[href="#tab-review"]').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to hook into page load.  Be it $document.ready, $window.load or window.onload.

Comment: That is a shortcut for document.ready. http://api.jquery.com/ready/ see `$(handler);`

Comment: I really can't figure it out how to put this code, same as the above one... Can you please write me the full code for this to work? Sorry again :(

Comment: Added script tags, just place them in your html.

Comment: Thank you guys for you awesome and quick help ;)

Comment: Hm, any idea how to put this between <?php ?> I need this to be executed with IF...?